# A special sum involving the von Mangoldt function

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Assuming the Prime Number Theorem (if you need), show that 
$$ \sum_{a\leq X} \left|\sum_{b\leq X/a} (\Lambda(b) - 1) \right| = o(X\log X) $$
where $\Lambda$ is the von Mangoldt function.

The big issue in my tries is that $\sum_{a\leq X} \sum_{b\leq X/a} 1 = O(X\log X)$ and I want little $o$ instead. This $(-1)$ somehow has to play a big role in neutralizing enough of the contribution of $\Lambda$, but I cannot see how.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{a \le X}o(X/a) = \sum_{a \le X/\log X} o(X/a) +O(\sum_{X/\log X<a \le X} X/a)$$ $$= o( X \log X) +O(X (\log X-\log (X/\log X)))= o(X\log X)$$

Comment: Seems nice. But why is the inner sum $o(X/a)$?

Comment: $\sum_{b \le X/a} \Lambda(b)-1 = o(X/a)$ separate the small $X/a$ and the large $X/a$

Comment: I do not get this "separation" :(